# No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using Mongodb Java async driver which is newly released. I am writing some simple test codes, which are:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://192.168.1.162:27017");
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mongodb1");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("t_test");
collection.count(
          new SingleResultCallback<Long>() {
              @Override
              public void onResult(final Long count, final Throwable t) {
                  System.out.println(count);
              }
          });

System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA------end”);
```

however, the callback function is not called, the console output is:

> 2017-06-21 13:57:58  [ INFO ]  Cluster created with settings {hosts=[192.168.1.162:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
>   2017-06-21 13:57:58  [ DEBUG ]  Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=192.168.1.162:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
>   2017-06-21 13:57:58  [ INFO ]  No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=192.168.1.162:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out

Comment: It means there is no server found at the address. Check the address is correct and reachable, and that a server is actually running.

Comment: The server is running,and the address is  reachable also。I can connected it by synchronization mode:     MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("192.168.1.162",27017)；